# URI regular expression for Java Problems

Tags: java, regex

I am trying to create a regular expression that will work for the following:

`GET://HOSTNAME1234:14159?sim=C:\sim.zip&bif=C:\bif.txt&wpt=C:\wpt.txt`
Or more simply:

`GET :// HOSTNAME1234 : 14159 ? sim = C:\sim.zip & bif = C:\bif.txt & wpt = C:\wpt.txt`

With this:

`(\w+)://(\w+)(:(\d+)\??)?((\w+)=([\/\.\\:\w]+)&?)*`

What I'm hoping to get out is something like this:

```
0: [0,72] GET://HOSTNAME1234:14159?arg0=C:\sim.zip&arg1=C:\bif.txt&arg2=C:\wpt.txt
1: [0,3] GET
2: [6,18] HOSTNAME1234
3: [18,24] :14159
4: [19,24] 14159
5: [57,72] arg2=C:\wpt.txt
6: [57,61] arg2
7: [62,72] C:\wpt.txt
```

Where 6 and 7 represent what I want, however I am not seeing "arg0" or "arg1". I assume I am doing something wrong with the `+` and `*` commands, but no combination of arrangements seem to work.

I am using this tool to help me: http://www.regexplanet.com/advanced/java/index.html / http://fiddle.re/h9b88

Comment: Curious why you're not using [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/URL.html) to parse the URL?

Comment: Hmm forgot about it. I will look into it now as a solution instead of regex! :)

Comment: Otherwise you're going to be making a serious nightmare for yourself! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

String to match:

`GET://HOSTNAME1234:14159?arg0=C:\sim.zip&arg1=C:\bif.txt&arg2=C:\wpt.txt`

Despite that you REALLY should be using a [URL parser](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/URL.html) to do this:

**Updated Method (works on full original string)**

`((\w+):\/\/(\w+):(\d+)\??|([^&]*?)=([^&]*)?)`

Working example: http://regex101.com/r/pL2wV9

---

**First Method (works, but requires a loop)**

Break the URL up into two parts:

Use `(\w+):\/\/(\w+):(\d+)\?(.*$)` to break the URL up into: http://regex101.com/r/pQ1vS9

**MATCH 1**

1. `GET`
2. `HOSTNAME1234`
3. `14159`
4. `arg0=C:\sim.zip&arg1=C:\bif.txt&arg2=C:\wpt.txt`

And then on group 4, use `([^&]*?)(?==)=?([^&]*)?` to match the query string once you've captured it, and iterate through it: http://regex101.com/r/bX3uM4

**MATCH 1**

1. `arg0`
2. `C:\sim.zip`

**MATCH 2**

1. `arg1`
2. `C:\bif.txt`

**MATCH 3**

1. `arg2`
2. `C:\wpt.txt`

---

**Disclaimer:** This is a really bad idea, and while I wanted to know if I could pull it off, using the URL parser is a much faster, much more accurate route.

Comment: I agree with the URL class. Someone pointed it out in an earlier comment and I am going to just use that. Appreciate what you did, I do wish there was a way to do this with one single regex though.

Comment: (That was me :D) One regex would be nice, and probably with enough time and effort it could be sorted out, but I just couldn't get it to capture the set of arguments on the right while retaining the structure on the left (of the ?)

Comment: I notice the Java URL class doesn't parse the query part of the URL... However your regex suggestion seems to do the job nicely :)

Comment: I had an epiphany, might be able to get it to work in one shot. Give me a few.

Comment: OK, try `((\w+):\/\/(\w+):(\d+)\??|([^&]*?)=([^&]*)?)` on the full string

Comment: By the way, what is the (?==) doing in the second regex? It seems to work but I just don't recognize what it means.

Comment: It's a lookahead, capturing the previous expression but excluding the = from the capture.